# windows batch regular expression

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of files under the format : TOTO-A#7.wav and I would like to rename them 
TOTO_7_As.wav (s for sharp) but I am not very good at regular expressions.
Do you know if its possible to do that easily?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-#." %%a in ('dir /A-D /B *.wav') do ren "%%a-%%b#%%c.wav" "%%a_%%c_%%bs.wav
```

If you want to execute previous Batch file in the command-line, just change each `%%` by `%`.

If you have other files with .wav extension and different format, change `*.wav` wild-card by a more precise one, for example: `????-?#?.wav`

Answer (score 0):

From the prompt:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=#" %a in ('dir /b /a-d *#*') do ren "%a#%b" "%aS%b"
```

As a batch line:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=#" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *#*') do ECHO(ren "%%a#%%b" "%%aS%%b"
```

Note that the `ECHO(` in the second example will simply **show** the required instructions. This is to allow the opportunity to ensure the correct instructions are generated. To **execute** the instructions, remove the `ECHO(`.

(Same trick *can* be used on the previous version, but it's a little tricky to read the result)

---

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3*delims=#-." %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *-*#*.*') do ECHO(ren "%%a-%%b#%%c.%%d" "%%a_%%c_%%bs.%%d"
```

will rename `TOTO-A#7.wav` to `TOTO_7_As.wav`

No idea what you mean by "sharp" - or "before between" fo that matter.

Comment: THank you for your help! Its proposing to replace TOTO-A#7.wav by TOTO_AS7.wav , which is not exactly what I want. I need the number to be before between "_".